# Check a string for 1 to infinite repetitions of asterisk (*) using JavaScript regex object

Tags: javascript, regex

I am completely crap in regex and I need a little help with a task. How do I check a string for a single character repetition (in my case *) using javasctipt regex object.

Specifically I need to check a string for 1 to n repetitions of * character. If the above case is true return true.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly trivial I am afraid:

```
/\*+/.test("*");           // true
/\*+/.test("hello world"); // false
```

Comment: I need to check repetition and the existence of asterisk only. I don't need to validate "tom*****" or "******tom" but "****". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many & they can be seperated, you can count the number of `*` in a string (using regex) with

```
"_*_*_*_*_".match(/\*/g).length; // 4
```

then compare against `n`

Comment: It does not matter if they are separated or not.

Comment: @Rhyono : anarchos78 didn't specify if they meant repetitions to be only consecutive `**` or anywhere in the string `*str*`, my answer doesn't care if they're consecutive.